# flex container ruining a border-radius, How to fix this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jsx

I have the positioning exactly how I want it, but the circle around the 58 is supposed to be a perfect circle, instead it's adjusting to the content in the container. How can I fix this problem?

Here is what it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb75A.png
Here is what I need it to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgQFI.png

Here is the JSX

```
<div className="second-col-container">
          <h2>Air Quality Index</h2>
             <div className="mod-container">
               <span className="index">58</span>

             <div className="para-mod">
               <span className="mod">Moderate</span>
              <div>
                Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there
                may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of
                people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.second-col-container {
  background-color: white;

  width: 250px;
  grid-area: air-index;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.second-col-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.para-mod {
  font-size: small;
  width: 60%;
  color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.index {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border: 3px solid rgb(223, 217, 217);
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.mod-container {
  display: flex;
}

.mod {
  font-size: large;

  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Never mind.  I didn't see the JSX. My bad. Upvoted it again. :)

Comment: @BobRodes They posted the Markup as JSX. The class syntax is camelCase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by giving the circle a fixed `height` and `width`. Then giving it a `border-radius of 50%`. and that would solve the first problem ( to make it into a perfect circle).

The second problem centering the text. Give the span a `display: flex` then use    `align-items: center;` and  `justify-content: center;` and you are good to go.

```
.index {
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: xx-large;
    border: 3px solid rgb(223, 217, 217);
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
    /* padding: 15px; */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With only `display: flex` applied to the parent div `.mod-container.`, your `<span class="index">` element containing the 2 digit number is growing to fill the content of its parent container.

Next, I centered the `.mod-container` flexbox content with `justify-content: center` and aligned using `align-items: flex-start`. This seems to match your desired image. (I can update class syntax to JSX if you need)

```css
.second-col-container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  grid-area: air-index;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.second-col-container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.para-mod {
  font-size: small;
  color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.index {
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  color: black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(223, 217, 217);
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 170, 11);
  padding: 15px;
}

.mod-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="second-col-container">
  <h2>Air Quality Index</h2>
     <div class="mod-container">
       <span class="index">58</span>

     <div class="para-mod">
       <span class="mod">Moderate</span>
      <div>
        Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there
        may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of
        people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```